# Existence of $1$-Lipschitz map between triangles

Tags: euclidean-geometry, metric-geometry

Consider two (Euclidean) triangles $T$ and $T'$.
Let's say that $T$ *majorizes* $T'$ if there exists a 1-Lipschitz map that sends
vertices to vertices and sides to sides (for some labeling of the vertices).

My question is, what are necessary and sufficient conditions for $T$ to majorize $T'$ ?

I know a sufficient condition.
Let's say that the lengths $(l_1, l_2, l_3)$ of $T$ and $(l_1', l_2', l_3')$
of $T'$ satisfy the *strong triangle inequalities* if
$l_i + l_j - l_k \ge l_i' + l_j' - l_k'$ for all pairwise distinct $i,j,k$.
Then if $T$ and $T'$ satisfy the strong triangle inequalities, then $T$ majorizes $T'$. Is this condition necessary ?

Comment: Here triangle is 1-dimensional ? I mean that $T$ is union of three sides with an induced metric $d$. That is $d$ is not intrinsic metric.

Comment: $T$ is the union of the sides with the metric induced by the Euclidean plane.

Comment: Posted also on MathOverflow: [Existence of $1$-Lipschitz map between triangles](https://mathoverflow.net/q/332026#333828). (I though that adding a link - at least in a comment - might be useful for others who see this post.)

Answer (score 1):

The "strong triangle inequality" is not necessary.
I use a modification of HK Lee example.

Let $T=ABC$ be an equilateral triangle with unit side length.
Consider the point $B'$ on the side $AB$ at distance $\varepsilon$ of $B$,
and consider the triangle $T'=AB'C$.

First, $T$ majorizes $T'$, because the projection of $T$ onto the (convex) $T'$ is a 1-Lipschitz map which sends vertices to vertices and sides to sides (for the obvious labeling).

Moreover, the strong triangle inequality fails.
Remark that $AB'=1-\varepsilon$ and $CB' = 1-\varepsilon + \varepsilon^2$.
We have $AC+CB-AB=1$ and $AC+CB'-AB' = 1 + \varepsilon^2$.

Answer (score 0):

**i)** Recall that $1$-Lipschitz map is area-decreasing. Note that
condition in OP (cf. Heron's formula) is not equivalent condition :

**Proof :** Consider an equilateral triangle $\Delta\ ABC$ of side
length $1$. When $A'\in [AB]$ with $|A-A'|=\varepsilon$, then
$|A-C|+|C-B| -|A-B|=1$. $$|A-C|+|C-A'|-|A-A'|$$ is close to $2$. Hence
we do have the condition, but there is $1$-Lipschitz map.

**ii)** I conjectured that the following is equivalent condition : $
\Delta A'B'C' $ is contained in $ \Delta ABC$

**Proof :** Consider the *following case* : $A=A',\ B=B'$ and $\angle \
ABC < \angle\ ABC'$.

When $A$ has a foot $A_f$ in $[BC]$ and $A$ has a foot $A_f'$ in $[BC']$, then note that $|A-A_f|<|A-A_f'|$ which shows that there is no $1$-Lipschitz map.

Comment: Your counter-example doesn't work, there is no 1-Lipschitz map between $ABC$ and $AA'C$. Consider $P$, the middle point of $AB$. Then the length $CP$ is lower than all the length $CP'$ for $P \in [AA']$, therefore one cannot map the point $P$ to the side $AA'$.

In particular, your condition ($A'B'C'$ is cointained in $ABC$) is not sufficient.